# Factoring out vector from sum?

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

Let X be a NxD matrix, let $\beta$ be a vector of dimension D.

Is there a way of factoring out $\beta$ to obtain such a result:

$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^D X^T_{ij}X_{ij}\beta_j = \beta (something)$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think so since $\beta$ depends on the index $j$ in the summation.

Comment: $\beta_j$ in the summation is supposed to mean the jth element of vector $\beta$, so not the entire vector depends on the summation. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What do you mean by $X_{ij}^T$ ? $X_{ij}$ is a number. Transposing it is not an error but it adds nothing !!!

Comment: @JeanMarie It is supposed to mean the element of $X^T$ at index ij. $X^T_{ij} = X_{ji}$.

Comment: ho, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=X^TX$, then I believe the quantity that you are trying to calculate is
$$\eqalign{
 \sum_j A_{jj} \beta_j
 &= {\rm Diag}(A)\cdot\beta 
 = {\rm Diag}(X^TX)\cdot\beta \cr
}$$
However, in your question it appears that you have swapped the subscripts on the $X^T$ term, otherwise the dimensions don't work out.